# What reason(s) exist to suppose that all degeneracy pressures can be overcome in Black-Hole formation?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, stars, quarks

In models of [stellar collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_collapse) to a black hole, it is a given that density increases without bound towards a singularity. Electron degeneracy I get. Neutron degeneracy I get. I assume there's some (theoretical) support that quark degeneracy can be ultimately overcome through some process Wikipedia doesn't describe - what is it?

Comment: and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173107/violation-of-pauli-exclusion-principle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have enough understanding of quark matter to know what would happen when it's compressed past the ability of quark degeneracy to withstand. One possibility is formation of an [electroweak star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_star#Electroweak_stars), but this is pretty speculative. I suspect we'll have to wait for string theory to make contact with the standard model before we'll know any more.

Answer (score 0):

Well not all or perhaps, but as far as if you have no problem with formation of neutron star, Black Hole just prohibits the release of information in view of general theory of relativity. So all that can be said is we dont know what is there after event horizon.